# I want to replace a word which is associated with a particular pattern/line

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

Say a file (socket.cfg) has the following

```
socket1:a:1.2.3.4:wso,ws1,ws2
socket2:b:2.5.6.7:ws3,ws5,ws7
```

Now I want to change only the IP where "socket1" contains in the line and the rest should remain the same. The data given to me would be only socket1 and IP to be changed.

I did try lineinfile and replace module but the whole pattern changes. Kindly help me out.
It is similar to the sed command like this `sed /socket1/<Ip_pattern>/<replacing_IP>` So this goes to socket1 line picks the IP and replaces only that. I want something like this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please share the ansible task and the output you are getting with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need,

```yaml
- name: replace the ip address
  lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/socket.cfg
    regexp: ^(socket1)(.*)(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)(.*)
    line: \g<1>\g<2>{{ inventory_hostname }}\g<4>
    backrefs: yes
```

Note: I have used regex groups while replacing the contents.

I have replaced the IP with the `inventory_hostname` which is localhost in my case, you can update it to whatever you want.

Input:

```
socket1:b:1.2.3.4:ws3,ws5,ws7
socket2:b:2.5.6.7:ws3,ws5,ws7
```

Output:

```
socket1:b:localhost:ws3,ws5,ws7
socket2:b:2.5.6.7:ws3,ws5,ws7
```

Comment: @Kushal, If you are satisfied with the answer you can mark it as accepted answer, so that it will be helpful for others and it will also close this question.